# Jasper login page not loading

Tags: tomcat, java

I'm wondering whether something needs to be in user tomcat's environment. 
I'm not going to run tomcat as root. BTW, does anyone use the installer or is everyone just downloading the war file and dropping it into tomcat?

```
  2017-03-06 18:15:08,177 ERROR JNDIResourceProvider,localhost-startStop-2:75 - error closing context
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:960)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.close(NamingContext.java:760)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.JNDIResourceProvider.close(JNDIResourceProvider.java:72)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.CompositeResourceProvider.close(CompositeResourceProvider.java:56)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.initialize(ResourcesFactory.java:163)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<init>(ResourcesFactory.java:92)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<clinit>(ResourcesFactory.java:89)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactoryContextListener.contextInitialized(ResourcesFactoryContextListener.java:23)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems better place StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340218/what-could-cause-javax-naming-operationnotsupportedexception-when-tomcat-start

Comment: It's not a programming question.

Comment: I had to scrutinize the installation.log file which contained,
Error running /opt/jasper/apache-ant/bin/ant import-ce -DimportFile=install_resources/export/js-catalog-postgresql-ce.zip:
BUILD FAILED

I ran the above with sudo and the build succeeded. Then Jasper server started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build everything as a non-root user, I believe, because you do *not* want to run tomcat as root. So I su - tomcat to run the installer but unfortunately this js-catalog-postgresql-ce.zip package refused to build unless I ran the build with sudo. Perhaps I should experiment with running the installer as root and then chowning -R /opt/jasper.